# Is the size limit for CQL map type per-row or per-table?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm thinking of making a table roughly like this

```
CREATE TABLE facts (
    instanceId uuid,
    factId text,
    value text,
    dimensions map<text,text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((instanceId), factId)
);
```

The dimensions are stuff like `region=UK`, `product=Cheese` etc.  I don't expect any given row to have more than a handful of dimensions and the set of facts for a given `instanceId` will use at most ~250 dimensions so that seems fine.

However globally the dimensions are liable to grow in an unbounded fashion over time because a different `instanceId` might use a different set of dimensions.

I read about the limit of 64k entries in a map and I'm not clear on whether that limit applies per-row or globally to the table.  I imagine it might be global because, as I understand it, a map is actually translated into a bunch of columns.  I'm unlikely to hit the limit during prototyping but I don't want to go down a path that leads to disaster!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I read about the limit of 64k entries in a map and I'm not clear on whether that limit applies per-row or globally to the table.

That limit applies per-row.  Cassandra doesn't have visibility into how many values a map column would have across an entire table.

> I imagine it might be global because, as I understand it, a map is actually translated into a bunch of columns.

No, the keys and values written to a map are stored as a single column value.  That's the tricky part when approaching thousands of entries in a map, is that a single column value cannot exceed 2GB.

> the set of facts for a given instanceId will use at most ~250 dimensions so that seems fine.

Given the information here, I think you'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The 64K limit applied to the maximum number of keys allowed in a column of type `map`, not to the whole table.

However, it is important to note that this limit was only enforced in older versions of Cassandra since the native protocol serialization format encoded the size of a `map` as an unsigned Java `short` integer which has a maximum value of `65536`. See the native protocol serialization format for `map` in [v1 specification here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.2/doc/native_protocol.spec#L538-L540) and [v2 specification here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0/doc/native_protocol_v2.spec#L745-L749).

Native protocol v3 (introduced in C* 2.1 by [CASSANDRA-6855](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6855)) [replaced the encoding to a Java `int`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/doc/native_protocol_v3.spec#L813-L817) so the bit of code which enforces the 64K limit was removed in C* 3.0.1 ([CASSANDRA-10374](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10374)).

Having said all that, it is still good practice to limit the size of CQL collections. They were designed to store a small number of elements and should never be allowed to grow unbounded. The recommended size for a whole partition is 100MB regardless of the number of rows in the partition or the number elements in a collection. Cheers!